# Delimited string between quotes?

Tags: java, android

I have some text file, and I need to read out just double quoted strings. I was trying with `split()` method, but I didn't get what I want. Example:

```
"000ABCD",000,HU,4614.850N,02005.483E,80.0m,5,160,1185.0m,,005,4619.650N,01958.400E,87.0m,1...
```

In this example, I just need string `000ABCD`. Any ideas?

Comment: this will help you http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/regex/Pattern.html

Comment: you can remove '"' from your string before you use split, you can use regexp to remove them, so yes we have hundreds ideas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
    String str="\"000ABCD\",000,HU,4614.850N,02005.483E,80.0m,5,160,1185.0m,,005,4619.650N,01958.400E,87.0m,1";
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\"(.*?)\"");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(str);
    while (m.find()) {                     
        System.out.println(m.group(1));
    }
```

Comment: @MarounMaroun I don't get your point. But this is working fine

Answer (score 3):

You can use this regex:

```
"\\"(.*?)\\""
```

---

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\"(.*?)\\"");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher("\"000ABCD\",000,HU,4614.850N,02005.");
if (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
}
```

It'll print: 000ABCD.

Answer (score 1):

```
int firstIndex = oldString.indexOf('"');
String data = oldString.substring(firstIndex+1, oldString.indexOf('"', firstIndex);
```